# how to insert row on table B when table A is updated, using a trigger in SQLlite

Tags: sqlite

Table A
userID
Name

Table B
UserID
Timestamp

I need to create a trigger to insert a row in table B, when A.Name changes. so far, i have:

CREATE TRIGGER NameUpdate
         AFTER UPDATE OF Name
            ON A
      FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO B(
                                UserID,
                                Timestamp
                            )
                            VALUES (
                                xxxxxxx,
                                DateTime('now') 
                            );
END;

XXXXXXX should be A.UserID that just changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the before/after values (according to relevance i.e. only new for inserts, old or new for updates and only old for deletes) using a prefix of **`old.`** or **`new.`** respectively.

Try :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER NameUpdate AFTER UPDATE OF Name ON A FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO B( UserID, Timestamp ) VALUES ( new.UserID, DateTime('now') ); 
    END
;
```

Or (*as the **UserID** column hasn't changed*) :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER NameUpdate AFTER UPDATE OF Name ON A FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO B( UserID, Timestamp ) VALUES ( old.UserID, DateTime('now') ); 
    END
;
```